# I rent out a room in my house, do I have to report the rent as income?

Tags: income-tax

Title says it all. Let me know if you need more details!

Thanks!

Comment: where do you live, and where is the house, the world does not have a single tax law yet!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is income, and you must report it in the US for tax reasons.  Don't forget to subtract loses such as utilities, depreciation, work done on the house might be able to qualify.

I think you report it on a Schedule E.  I rent out a home and taxact.com walks me through how much money I made, then my expenses.  Things like mileage, repair bills, administrative fees for a management company, utilities and the mortgage all make for a big loss for me.  I am certain some of those things apply to you and your income can be lowered.

- http://www.irs.gov/publications/p17/ch09.html
- http://www.real-estate-owner.com/renting-a-room.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes you do.  You can also deduct a percentage of your home expenses such as utilities, interest, property taxes, etc...